# Catch all http requests and send urls to parent

Tags: javascript, node.js

server.js

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(85);

function onRequest(req, res) {
   if (req.url === "/"){
         fs.readFile('/index.html',function(data,err){
            if (err){
                console.log(err);
                return res.end(err);
            }

            res.write(data);
            res.end();
        });
    }
    var queryData = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
    if (queryData.url) {
        request({
            url: queryData.url
        }).on('error', function(e) {
            res.end(e);
        }).pipe(res);
    }
    else {
        res.end("no url found");
    }
}
```

What this program does is get a file from a remote location of the user's choosing by adding a query parameter to the end of the url as follows

`www.myprogramdomain:85/?url=http://www.domain.com/index.html`

If I try to do the above bet set `url=http://us.battle.net` It shows a webpage without the css. I go into the browser console and see that the page does not have any css or javascript because the scripts are included with local tags such as '/scripts/myscript.js' or something. What I plan to do is embed the webdata from the server inside of an iframe and intercept the requests for files as they come.

The question is, inside of the iframe, how do I intercept http requests and get the url the request is trying to send to the server. Preferably as a string. I searched around for a long time. I even attempted to replace all instances of 'http' with 'http://www.myprogramdomain.com:85/?url=http' but that did not work as expected as some of the urls such as '/scripts/js.js' do not have 'http' in it. That's why I want to be able to intercept requests and get the urls from the request. Or maybe I want to run a script every time an http request is made from the iframe.

**What I want to do is intercept the http request inside of the iframe and replace it with my own request.**

If you need some more explanation DO NOT BE AFRAID TO ASK FOR MORE INFORMATION!

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to intercept all resource loading requests in a browser from plain Javascript in your page.  You could probably do it from a browser plugin.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to know how to intercept ALL requests. But even then, how do I build a browser plugin to do that?

Comment: @ahitt6345 If you have the level of access needed to set up a browser plugin, why not just use a traditional HTTP proxy?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Provide a mirror to a website? This is not a trivial problem to solve and would require multiple levels of mirroring, the first of which you're trying to do. (That is to say, solving your current problem would introduce more problems which would be more complex to solve. It would be better to describe your end goal first)

Comment: @tcooc Basically, yeah that's what I'm trying to do. My end goal is to display a webpage with all the css and javascript in it through the iframe.

Comment: @Brad What do you mean HTTP proxy? Do you mean something like windscribe or something? If that's the case I don't want to pay for the service. But If you mean using a library like node-http, It provides a way to get to the page, but then there I am meeting the same issue I have in this question. Can you explain?

Comment: @ahitt6345 i deleted my unhelpful answer.  However, I guess I dont understand the problem.  It sounds like you want to show an html page in an iframe?  Im sure there is a good reason, just asking to clear it up, why doesnt the iframe just work?  Give a url to an iframe it shows a webpage with css and javascript.

Comment: @Chris it works in the iframe, that works fine, But I wanted to figure out how to intercept http requests inside of the iframe and replace them with my own.

Comment: What I mean it works fine is that the content from the server is displayed inside of the iframe, but the css and scripts are not present in the iframe.

Comment: The scripts that are imported with `<script>` or `<link>` tags, that is.

Comment: I am almost there, give me some time

Comment: Okay I have updated the code and its working like a charm for most of the sites. Don't check google's sites as they will block most resources based on the headers. Give a try..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you give a try of the following modified code and refactor it further as required..

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(85);

function parseCookies (req) {
    var list = {},
        rc = req.headers.cookie;

    rc && rc.split(';').forEach(function( cookie ) {
        var parts = cookie.split('=');
        list[parts.shift().trim()] = decodeURI(parts.join('='));
    });

    return list;
}

function onRequest(req, res) {
   if (req.url === "/"){
         fs.readFile('/index.html',function(data,err){
            if (err){
                console.log(err);
                return res.end(err);
            }

            res.write(data);
            res.end();
        });
    }

    var getExternal = function(extUrl) {
       request({
            url: extUrl
        }).on('error', function(e) {
            res.end(e);
        }).pipe(res);
    };

    var queryData = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
    if (queryData.url) {
        var externalUrl = url.parse(queryData.url);
        //res.cookie('externalBaseUrl', externalUrl.protocol + '//' + externalUrl.host);
        res.writeHead(200, {
        'Set-Cookie': 'externalBaseUrl=' + externalUrl.protocol + '//' + externalUrl.host
    });
        getExternal(queryData.url);
    }
    else {
        var cookies = parseCookies(req);
        if (cookies && cookies.externalBaseUrl) {
           //var urlPath = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
            getExternal(cookies.externalBaseUrl + req.url);
        } else {
           res.end("no url found");
        }
    }
}
```

I checked this as http://localhost:85/?url=https://iiwebi.com which works as cool as a cucumber :-)

Comment: I am almost there, give me some time to edit the above

Comment: Okay I have updated the code and its working like a charm for most of the sites. Don't check google's sites as they will block most resources based on the headers.

Comment: But, only because it opens scripts and css like I asked. How would I intercept XMLHttp requests?

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is that you're trying to create a "Man in the Middle" (MITM) Proxy, that will intercept all requests, maybe modify them a bit, then forward them to another url.

In this case, I suggest you use a library that does that already. You can google "node mitm". I found these libraries, you can review their api and see if they provide what you need

- [node-mitm](https://github.com/moll/node-mitm)
- [node-http-mitm-proxy](https://github.com/joeferner/node-http-mitm-proxy)
- [node-mitm-proxy](https://github.com/horaci/node-mitm-proxy)

This will make you able to forward `http://myprogramdomain:85/index.html`

to `http://www.domain.com/index.html`

but you won't be able to use a query string parameter like `?url=http://www.domain.com/index.html`

because while this will work to serve the first page (index.html) any requests with a relative path (images, css) will not have that `url=` which is why it's not working in your code. The path on your server and the end server should be exactly the same.

Comment: I don't want to redirect the person, I want the person to view the webpage while still in my website.

Comment: This is exactly what a mitm proxy will do. The user will see your domain while his request is being invisibly sent to the other server on the back end. He will see the other server pages (which you can modify) but he will think it's your server as it will be your domain url in his browser.

Answer (score 1):

You could inline the script and css files in the document!

NodeJS:

1) Request the document
2) Search the documents for script/css
3) Request the script/css files
4) Inline the script/css files into the document
5) Send the document to your client